# How to upload an image from a react native app (Expo) to a django server

Tags: javascript, django, react-native, expo

I am using the expo image picker to let users upload a picture to a Django server, but I have run into an error where the image I upload is always null.  The post request goes through, but the image is never stored but somehow still seems to be sent. From what I have read I need to upload the image as base64 so I have set the picker to take the image in base64, whereas I had been using a uri for the upload but I still get a null image field in the database record.

upload url `path('feed/', views.ListCreatePost.as_view(), name="post_feed"),`

```
const [image, setImage] = useState(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        (async () => {
            if (Platform.OS !== 'web') {
                const { status } = await ImagePicker.requestCameraRollPermissionsAsync();
                if (status !== 'granted') {
                    alert('Sorry, we need camera roll permissions in order to make a post!');
                }
            }
        })();
    }, []);

    let postForm = new FormData();

    const makePost = async ()  => {
           try{
               console.log('salvo');
               console.log(image);
               let photo = {
                   uri: image.uri,
                   type: 'image/*',

               };
               console.log('photo');
               console.log(photo);
               postForm.append('user_id', user);
               postForm.append('content', content);
               postForm.append("image", photo);

               let response = await fetch('https://mdrn02.herokuapp.com/api/v1/feed/',
                   {
                       method: 'POST',
                       headers: {
                           Accept: 'application/json',
                           'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
                       },
                       body: postForm
                   });
               console.log('response');
               console.log(response);
               let json = await response.text();

               console.log('response json post');
               console.log(json);


           } catch (error){
               console.log('error posting');
               console.log(error);
               Alert.alert(
                   "Error in fields",
                   "Try again",
                   [{text: 'Close'}]
               );
           }
        };

    const pickImage = async () => {
        let result = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
            mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.All,
            allowsEditing: true,
            aspect: [4, 3],
            quality: 1,
            base64: true
        });

        console.log(result);

        if (!result.cancelled) {
            setImage(result.uri);
        }
    };
```

model

```
class Post(models.Model):
    user_id = models.ForeignKey('User', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    content = models.CharField(max_length=280)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='posts/', null=True, blank=True)
```

view

```
class ListCreatePost(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = models.Post.objects.all()
    serializer_class = serializers.PostSerializer
```

serializer

```
class PostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        fields = (
            'id',
            'user_id',
            'time',
            'content',
            'image'
        )
        model = models.Post
```

EDIT:
I am fairly certain that the error lies in the javascript, and in how the data is sent to the server.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind installing additional dependencies, I would suggest you install the excellent [drf-extra-fields](https://github.com/Hipo/drf-extra-fields) package. This allows you to add a base64 field (among many others) to your serializer:

```py
from drf_extra_fields.fields import Base64ImageField

class PostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    image = Base64ImageField()

    class Meta:
        fields = (
            'id',
            'user_id',
            'time',
            'content',
            'image'
        )
        model = models.Post
```

Comment: Cheers, I will give it a go and see how it pans out